# Program is not accessible from the command-line

Tags: command-line, bashrc, paths, environment

I am trying to use BUSCO program for bioinformatic analysis. BUSCO need to Agustus program as dependency. According to BUSCO’s user guide I must add Augustus to path and I did it as following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/dr/augustus-3.2.2/bin    
export PATH=$PATH:/home/dr/augustus-3.2.2/script    
export AUGUSTUS_CONFIG_PATH=/home/dr/augustus-3.2.2/config/
```

to ensure that adding is in correct way I ran augustus in command line and it worked well, but when I ran BUSCO I get following ERROR:

"Augustus is not accessible from the command-line, please add it to environment"

What is wrong that I get this error and how can fix it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you link the guide you are following?

Comment: Please put those lines in your `/home/dr/.bashrc` file then close and open terminal and try again.

Comment: According to [BUSCO_v2.0_userguide.pdf](https://gitlab.com/ezlab/busco/raw/master/BUSCO_v2.0_userguide.pdf) the second directory is `/scripts` not `/script`

Comment: script here was typographical mistake, i wrote it correctly in terminal.

Comment: no more help? At first I was disappointed

Comment: Exactly how do you call augustus from command line? So that I can try to verify what's happening with the validation (btw, the validation method in question is `BUSCO.Analysis.cmd_exists`).